# Attribute Error when I try to import tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compiler.mlir.quantization.stablehlo.quantization_config_pb2' has no attribute 'CalibrationOptions'

Was trying to import tensorflow, it has been working fine for the past 2 years. I installed tf-keras and after that i get this error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.